# Is there some software tool that analyzes audio to produce pitch information?

Tags: guitar, software, tablature

Such a tool would be extremely useful to me. What I want it to do is, given a sound file be able to get the pitch every time it changes. I don't know how this could be done, or even if it's possible. As a beginner guitarist, I find manually transcribing music into tabs to be extremely difficult, especially for fast-played music like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgpoAnChpX0).

I thought about trying to make a tool like this myself, but this type of signal processing is beyond my ability, since the tool should be able to separate instruments playing together to get the accurate pitch. I'm really hoping there's an alternative.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Transcribe! is a Windows program that can help pick out the notes from a spectrogram, as well as change tempo and pitch independently.  It also has other features that make transcription and practice easier.

Comment: I'll second that; I'm using Transcribe to learn Charlie Christian's solos, and it's made a difficult process much easier.

Comment: Put it in an answer then. By the way, @hassan, what is your operating system?

Comment: @Luke Mac OS X. I haven't tried Transcribe, but from what I understand it's similar to Capo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a Mac or iPhone/iPad, you could use **[Capo](http://supermegaultragroovy.com/products/Capo/)** to do this.

Comment: I just downloaded the trial and transcribed the first part of the song I linked to (although the spectrogram was really messy, possibly because of the song's poor quality). Anyway, what a great tool! I love it! I'm surprised it's only for mac though. Anyway, great suggestion.

Comment: There's a good website for checking out similar software, alternativeto.net. It list a couple of [alternatives to capo](http://alternativeto.net/software/capo/), and you can add more, if you find them.

Comment: Does it handle microtones that seemed necessary for the sample clip Hassan gave?

Comment: @UlfÅkerstedt It does seem to handle them (somewhat). I can zoom in pretty far and get good detail, but like I said, the spectrogram it draws looks rather messy, and the farther you zoom in, the messier it gets. I haven't tried the program for cleaner recordings though.

Comment: Capo does **not** transcribe audio and identify pitches automatically. It is designed to provide tools to *assist* a human being in figuring out this information.

Comment: @WheatWilliams True. But Capo makes the process significantly easier. For the past few days, I've been trying the two apps you linked to in your answer. Yes, they are more automated than Capo, but they weren't accurate enough to be useful for the examples I tried. Melodyne was good to know about though, because it does so much more that transcription, and is an excellent editor for certain things.

Answer (score 0):

### [Neuratron AudioScore](http://www.neuratron.com/audioscore.htm)

### [Celemony Melodyne](http://www.celemony.com/cms/)

I don't have any direct experience with these products. Please check out their Web sites and try their demos.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 apps in Apple's iTunes iOS App store that attempt do something like that to some small degree: the HotPaw Productions Sing-inTuna app, and Music Spectrograph.  With the latter app you will still need to manually separate out each instrument's note pitch from the mixed together overtone series.